# itext AES encrypted PDF still displays text properly

Tags: pdf, encryption, itext, aes

we have encrypted a sample pdf file using itext 5.
the code generates an encrypted pdf output and
Adobe pdf reader says it is AES-256 bit encrypted but any user can read its content easily.

How could we shuffle the text inside the pdf so that without a custom AES decryption program the texts inside the pdf can not be read.

thanks in advance

```
public static final String SRC = " /2016.pdf";
public static final String DEST = " /enc.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new crypto().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
}


public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(null, "World".getBytes(),
        PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Password encryption isn't to be trusted if you don't encrypt the document with a user password. Many PDF viewers completely ignore the permissions you set. Just out of curiosity: what did you expect from encryption, and can you explain that expectation using a paragraph from ISO 32000? Because the way you describe your requirement sounds awkward to me.

Comment: Thanks for the swift comment.The requirement is that every pdf should be encrypted and an encrypted pdf document should only be accessible through the legacy software of the company.Which is supposed to read the file first , decrypt it and display through its embedded pdf viewer component. Our interpretation is that when it is double clicked on windows the adobe reader or any other reader should not open it.

Comment: That requirement sounds like external file encryption, not internal pdf encryption.

Comment: True , any clue or example is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried certificate encryption? Password encryption really isn't the solution for your problem. Especially if you pass `null` as user password. In your code, you only define an `owner` password, which means that you allow everyone to see the document, but you want to restrict the way the document is used (and as I explained many viewers don't respect the restrictions you defined).

Comment: For encrypting the PDF in its entirety you could look at CMS (cryptographic message syntax) or PGP encryption. PGP also has password encryption if you require that. Note that in both cases you would need to decrypt before the file is even considered PDF, no PDF reader will be able to parse it. Needless to say: you don't want to *implement* either container format, use a library!